# Calling a wp_query $posts causes a 500 error

Tags: wp-query, variables, 500-internal-error

I had a very basic `wp_query`, below:

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'draft' ),
    'posts_per_page'         => '15',
);

// The Query
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This caused a 500 error. When I changed `$posts` back to the more traditional `$query`, everything was fine. Is `$posts` a reserved variable?

Comment: Where did you place this code?

Comment: it would be better if it had been prefixed in core, to avoid collision ;-)

Comment: @birgire Yes that makes no sense at all only prefixing `$wp_query` which is prefixed with `wp_` and not othere like `$post` and `$posts`. I have seen a huge amount of users here which uses `$posts` as a local variable without knowing it is actually a reserved global, and almost always, their issue is related to this

Comment: yes these global swamps can be muddy, we don't know what's gonna bite us in the feet when we go there, like demonstrated here ;-) But it's very natural to think one could use such generic variable names like `$posts` and `$post` @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is `$posts` a reserved variable

Yes, it is, `$posts` is the global variable which holds the array of posts from the main query. This is how it is set:

```
$GLOBALS['posts'] = & $wp_query->posts;
```

Just remember, `$posts === $GLOBALS['posts']`